# Ajuda com um script simples no Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Boa noite

Eu sou novo aqui, prazer em conhece-los

Eu gostaria da ajuda de vcs, eu não sei nada de programação, porém creio eu que 
esse script que estou em mente deva ser simples

Eu queria um script que pega o nome de uma imagem dentro do código fonte de uma página (sem a extensão) e um código que está presente na url do site

Fazendo assim que geraria uma url com as informações acima

Por exemplo:

www.nomedosite.com/123

Dentro desse site teria uma imagem "abc.jpg"

Junto com essas informações geraria uma url assim

www.linkgerado.com/abc/id=123

Se alguém me ajudar eu ficaria muito grato
Abraços

Comment: Que linguagem você está usando? Só tem 1 imagem na página que você quer pegar? Vc quer pegar essa imagem de qualquer URL? A URL é externa ou do seu projeto?

Comment: Em javascript. É um site externo e a imagem está em qualquer url aonde tem um player de video, ela é a thumb do video, em todas url essa thumb está localizada em uma pasta na aba source